# How to get the number of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, scripting, difference

I have a user database and I need help forming a query.

```
Table = users
fields = sign_in_count , last_sign_in_at
```

These are two queries which gives me following results :-

```
select *
from users
where last_sign_in_at >= '2015-08-01' and sign_in_count != ''
```

gives me 131000 rows.

```
select *
from users
where last_sign_in_at between '2015-05-01' and '2015-09-11' and
      sign_in_count <> ''
```

gives me 203000 rows.

so the difference of users in 72,000 users who have signed in at least once between 05/15 to 08/15.

I need to know the no of users from these 72k users who have logged in more than once.

Comment: I would suggest you start by tagging your question with the database you are actually using.  SQL Server and MySQL are two different databases.

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?  Also, what is the datatype of sign_in_count?

Comment: (Aside: please do not mark your questions as urgent. Readers here are volunteers, and they generally do not like to be rushed).

Comment: A bit OT, but `sign_in_count <>''` implies that this field has a alphanumeric type rather then a numeric. It seems a better practice to make such fields numeric, not null, with a default of 0. In that case you could write `sign_in_count > 0` which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The query below would work assuming the `users` table has `user_id` column.

```
    select count(user_id) from
     (
    select user_id --replace it with appropriate user identifier column
    from (select * from users
    where last_sign_in_at between '2015-05-01' and '2015-09-11' 
    and sign_in_count != ''
    and user_id not in (select user_id from users 
    where last_sign_in_at >= '2015-08-01' and sign_in_count!='')
     ) t
    group by user_id 
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with

```
Select count(*) from users
where last_sign_in_at  between '2015-05-01' and '2015-08-01'
and sign_in_count > 1
```

Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You want to query total number of user in desired time frame who have logged in more then once.

But you are only querying to find the total number of users in between '2015-05-01' and '2015-08-01' and sign_in_count <> ''.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking the remainder of the two `where` conditions in a derived table for a `count()`:

```
select count(*) 
from
   (select * from users 
    where last_sign_in_at > '2015-05-01' 
    and last_sign_in_at < '215-08-01'
    and sign_in_count != '')
```